Application of the Löwenheim-Skolem Theorem for theories with uncountable signatures?
The Löwenheim-Skolem asserts the following:

For a first order (L_(ω,ω)) theory with signature σ, every infinite σ - structure M and every infinite cardinal κ ≥ |σ|there is a σ-structure N such that |N| = κ and such that:

if κ < |M| then N is an elementary substructure of M;
if κ ≥ |M| then N is an elementary extension of M



Source:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%B6wenheim%E2%80%93Skolem_theorem

For σ is uncountable, we get that the downwards Löwenheim-Skolem property only goes down |σ| (i.e., a model M >|σ| will have an elementary substructure of cardinality |σ| minimum).
The statement:

If a first order theory T has an infinite model then it has models of all infinite cardinalities.

Only applies if the signature σ is countable.
So having an uncountable signature σ leads to an increase in the Löwenheim numbers l(L) and Hanf number h(L) of this logic. Specifically we can gather that the h(L) = |σ| and l(L)= |σ|? (unless we introduce a weaker notion of the Löwenheim-Skolem theorem where l(L) and h(L) < |σ| but the guaranteed models of all infinite cardinalities are not necessarily elementary substructures or extensions).
Question: For a first order theory T with an uncountable signature σ, can we have infinite (i.e., of cardinality ℵ_0) models maximal in with respect to cardinality (given it T has no models M ≥ |σ|)?
Sidenote: If we say a logic L_(k,λ) has Löwenheim number l(L) and Hanf number h(L) are we assuming a countable signature (unless otherwise specified)?
This question: About Löwenheim-Skolem Theorem seemes related but doesn't specifically answer my question on maximal models and Hanf numbers.

Hi, welcome to MSE. It seems to me that the statement of Loewenheim-Skolem that you quote from Wikipedia immediately implies that the answer to your question "for a first order theory, can we have infinite models maximal with respect to cardinality?" is no. The statement never requires that $|M| \ge |\sigma|$ - is this your confusion?

@Izaakvan van Dongen Thank you Izaakvan, from what I've gathered the statement "If a theory has an infinite model then it has models of all infinite cardinalities" remains true. But if the signature is uncountable then "We cannot find an elementary substructure or extension of M of cardinality ℵ_0" (this can only occur if σ is countable). Is this true?

The statement from Wikipedia always remains true. So if $M$ is infinite and $\sigma$ is uncountable, it's still true that for any cardinal $\kappa \ge |\sigma|$, there will be an elementary substructure/extension of $M$ of cardinality $\kappa$. It is possible that if $M$, $\sigma$ are both uncountable then there are no countable models. It's also possible that if $|M| = \aleph_0$ and $\sigma$ is uncountable, then there is some uncountable cardinal with no models of that cardinality. But there will always be an even larger cardinal such that $M$ has an elementary extension of that cardinality.

Thank you! This does clear up my confusion.

For first-order theories "going up" is very simple, it is just a compactness argument. In particular: if a first-order theory $T$ has an infinite model it has arbitrarily large models.
Indeed, suppose $M$ is an infinite model of $T$. Let $\kappa$ be any cardinal and add $\kappa$ many new constants to the language of $T$. Then let $T'$ be an expansion of $T$ in this new language expressing that all these newly added constants are distinct. Using $M$ we easily see that $T'$ is finitely consistent. By the compactness theorem $T'$ must then have a model, which is in particular a model of $T$ with at least $\kappa$ many distinct elements, i.e. of cardinality at least $\kappa$.

And this is true even if the signature/language is uncountable? So we can say l(L) and h(L) = ℵ_0 (ruling out any maximal models) but if the signature is uncountable these arbitrarily large models may not necessarily be elementary substructures and extensions of an infinite model M?

In the question I linked, the answer states that this can only occur if the language is countable.

@SJe967 Yes, the above proof works even if the language is uncountable. The size of the language really only matters when "going down", so when you try to find an elementary substructure. The "going down" part is used to get models of an exact cardinality (as is talked about in the question you linked): you first go up to something that is at least big enough (like in my answer here) and then go down to the specific cardinality that you want.
